# Controllers granularity in AngularJs

Tags: angularjs

Maybe it's silly question but I'm coming from Asp.net MVC world and normal manner is t create single controller per model ie.:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {...}
    public ActionResult Details(long id)
    {...}
    public ActionResult Edit(long id)
    {...}
}
```

On the other hand in AngularJs app I'm creating controller per view like:

```
app.controller('FooDetailsController', function ($scope, $routeParams, FooService) {
    $scope.foo = FooService.get({ id: $routeParams.id })
});

app.controller('FooListController', function ($scope, FooService) {
    $scope.foos = FooService.query();
});

...
```

How should I create controllers in AngularJs, what is best practice? This one looks really awkward for me.

Comment: I've normally seen it the way you describe with one controller per view, but you can use the same controller for multiple views if you want.

Comment: Yes, but how "single" controller should looks like? ie. on Details view I don't want to load collection of objects and other way on Collection view I don't want to get detail model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you're checking the $routeParam to see if there is a detail to look for, if not, looking for the list. http://plnkr.co/edit/jAK31F?p=preview

Comment: Yes,but I was hopping for something else than if-else madness :) Thanks though.

Comment: If it's one controller for 2 views, that's where you are. I think you'll find the one controller per view is not that awkward because most of the item-specific manipulation should be in the FooService anyway. That would look more like "Foo.detail", "Foo.list",  "Foo.getChildren", etc.

Comment: After "couple" of lines of code I need to strongly agree and I feel pretty comfortable with controller per view. Thanks

Comment: Where are you guys now ? I've been struggling to find the right balance. Is it your FIRST WAY TO GO to make 1 view = 1 controller when starting a project now ??? Do you guys systematicaly push it to a directive as its a natural way to tie controller and view in angular ???

Comment: If you're struggling with how to make a controller fit a use case, chances are the functionality doesn't belong in a controller.